# Android Xperia X10 SoundPool

Tags: android, audio

I have had some reports from users of my android app that there is no sound being played on the X10. I'm a bit confused as it works on all other phones that I have tried, Neus One, Hero, Droid. I'm using the SoundPool class to play sounds, has anybody else had similar issues with the X10?

Thanks,
Gaz

Comment: Just to say I've not tried SoundPool, but I've seen audio issues on the X10 that differ from all other phones and OS versions (primarily related to Ringtones and audio volume).

Comment: I'm receiving similar reports for an app I wrote.  Though apparently the sound was initially working and now doesn't.  Would be keen to know if anybody has any clue as to what might cause it or how to fix it.

Comment: My problematic sounds are 11.025khz mono MP3s played via the SoundPool for what it's worth.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed my similar problems (see comments above) by converting my MP3s to Oggs and using MediaPlayer rather than SoundPool.  I'm not sure which of the two changes was responsible for the fix as I don't have an X10 to test on but users reported that the new version now works.

Comment: Thanks for the replies Dan, would be nice if someone with an X10 would do a few quick tests for us.......

I'm getting lots of 1 star ratings because of this issue :(

Comment: When using soundPool, in some xperia devices, noise kind of sound is producing for wav files with high bitrate 2116 kbps. SO downgrading the bitrate to 16 bit PCM (ie around 1000kbps) seems to fix the issue with soundpool.